# Can't access localhost from android device through wifi

Tags: xampp, localhost, wifi

I've tried to access my xampp localhost from android devices through wifi connection, but I dunno why my android phone screen notify me *This site can't be reached*

I've tried :
use ip:port in address bar but it's useless

IP of wifi connection:

[image]

my xampp version is : XAMPP for windows 5.6.30

anyone can help me out, please

Comment: Refer to Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection in your cmd, take IP address at that part, it work for me last time but now cannot work already, you try have a try there